# Android: Custom Titlebar causes app to crash

Tags: android, titlebar

Ok, I am following this example of creating a custom title bar: http://thetransientway.com/?p=100. the end result should be like this:

[image: title bar]
<sub>(source: [thetransientway.com](http://thetransientway.com/tutorials/android/content/customtitlebar_output.png))</sub>

The problem is, the moment I open up the app, it just crashes. This is what I have right now:

Activity file:

```
package u.nav.it;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class UNavitActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
    }
}
```

custom_title.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#005BAA"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

<Button
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:text="Button"
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginRight="7dp"  >
</Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Title Content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

     <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="u.nav.it"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".CustomTitlebarActivityActivity" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I do not use an emulator. I just export and install on my phone for testing. My emulator does the freeze on [2012-02-12 15:46:00 - UNavit] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched... thing that i googled but could not find a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined the activity `UNavitActivity` in your manifest. Replace *CustomTitlebarActivityActivity* with *UNavitActivity* and i hope it should work.

Answer (score 1):

as already said you've not defined your activity
probably you changed the name of the app instead of following the example's one, but you didn't change

```
android:name=".CustomTitlebarActivityActivity"
```

in the manifest file

edit it into

```
android:name=".UNavitActivity"
```